# Using np.where to find matching row in 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I would like to know how I use `np.where` with 2D array

I have the following array:

```
arr1 = np.array([[ 3.,  0.],
                 [ 3.,  1.],
                 [ 3.,  2.],
                 [ 3.,  3.],
                 [ 3.,  6.],
                 [ 3.,  5.]])
```

I want to find this array:

```
arr2 = np.array([3.,0.])
```

But when I use `np.where()`:

```
np.where(arr1 == arr2)
```

It returns:

```
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]))
```

I can't understand what it means. Can someone explain this for me?

Comment: Have you looked at `arr1 == arr2`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably wanted all rows that are equal to your `arr2`:

```
>>> np.where(np.all(arr1 == arr2, axis=1))
(array([0], dtype=int64),)
```

Which means that the first row (zeroth index) matched.

---

The problem with your approach is that numpy broadcasts the arrays (visualized with [`np.broadcast_arrays`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_arrays.html)):

```
>>> arr1_tmp, arr2_tmp = np.broadcast_arrays(arr1, arr2)
>>> arr2_tmp
array([[ 3.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  0.],
       [ 3.,  0.]])
```

and then does elementwise-comparison:

```
>>> arr1 == arr2
array([[ True,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False],
       [ True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

and `np.where` then gives you the coordinates of every `True`:

```
>>> np.where(arr1 == arr2)
(array([0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int64))
#       ^---- first match (0, 0)
#          ^--- second match (0, 1)
#             ^--- third match (1, 0)
#  ...
```

Which means `(0, 0)` (first row left item) is the first `True`, then `0, 1` (first row right item), then `1, 0` (second row, left item), ....

---

If you use `np.all` along the first axis you get all rows that are completly equal:

```
>>> np.all(arr1 == arr2, axis=1)
array([ True, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Can be better visualized if one keeps the dimensions:

```
>>> np.all(arr1 == arr2, axis=1, keepdims=True)
array([[ True],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False],
       [False]], dtype=bool)
```